# Difference between TYPEKIND and TYPECATEGORY

Tags: abap, rtts

Can anyone tell me the difference between 
`CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR=>kind` and `CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR=>type_kind`.
Just want to know whether it is a structure or not. But which one do I have to use?

Answer (score 2):

The constants KIND_xxx and TYPEKIND_xxx pretty much answer your question.

To see if something is a structure check if `KIND` equals `CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR=>KIND_STRUCT`. You can then further use `TYPE_KIND` to see if it is a flat or deep structure.